# function to truncate as string using a start and end point

Tags: php

I need to select a portion of a string. I know the start and end point of the string (found using strpos) but I don't know how to select this portion of the string....substr won't work as the string can be different lengths. I need to be able to truncate the string by saying start at this character and end at this character.

I'm sure there's a way to do this but can't seem to finds it in the manual

Comment: If you know the start and end, why can't `substr` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned substr is perfectly fine.

I am writing this answer just to provide you with example (as it seems you are a bit confused)

```
$string = 'This string is too long and I want only a portion of it where I know the start and end position of the portion';

// now if you want to get everything between "too long" and "position" and you know the position for start and end which in this case are:
$start = 15; // 16th character
$end = 95; // 96th character

// from inside out first substr cuts the end of the string at requred character, the other substr cuts the beginning of the string
// resulting in portion beginning at 16th character and ending at 96th character.
$portion = substr(substr($string, 0, -(strlen($string) - $end)), $start);

var_dump($portion);
```

Hope that helps you out :)

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

substr does this perfectly, it takes start position and length.

calculate length with (end position - start position)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the length of the string with this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

substr — Return part of a string
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )

Returns the portion of string specified by the start and length parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Use `substr()` with the variables you've got from `strpos()`;

```
$string = 'My sub string in a string';
$substring = 'sub string';
echo substr( $string, strpos( $string, $substring ), strlen( $substring ) );
// echoes "sub string";
```

kind of a stupid example, but you get the point :)

Comment: OF Course! Sorry think I had a blond moment there. It's been a hard day! Thanks all.